# RadListView - Update a textfield value

Tags: nativescript, radlistview

I have a product list in RadListView and each product has a quantity selector. User can press + - buttons to increase or decrease the quantity or can type into the textfield too. All these controls are working and data is being updated in the observable but not on the screen. THe value being shown in the textfield doesn't update on screen. Here's the code:

```
<StackLayout col="1" orientation="horizontal" class="qtySelect bg-secondary">
    <Label class="mdi qtyButtons" text="&#xe15c;" pid="{{ id }}" tap="qtyDecrease" />
    <TextField text="{{ quantity }}" keyboardType="Number" verticalAlignment="top" class="qtyText" />
    <Label class="mdi qtyButtons" text="&#xe147;" pid="{{ id }}" tap="qtyIncrease" />
</StackLayout>
```

JS

```
function findById(pid){
    var index;
    products.forEach (function(elem, i) {
        if(elem.id == pid){
            index = i;
        }
    });
    return index;
}

exports.qtyDecrease = function(args){
    var index = findById(args.object.pid);
    console.log(index);
    var product = products.getItem(index);

    if(product.min_order < product.quantity)
        product.quantity = parseInt(product.quantity)-1;
    else
        Toast.makeText("Minimum quantity of "+product.min_order+" is required for this product.").show();
    products.set(index, product);
}

exports.qtyIncrease = function(args){
    var index = findById(args.object.pid);
    console.log(index);
    var product = products.getItem(index);

    product.quantity = parseInt(product.quantity)+1;
    products.set(index, product);
}
```

If I scroll the item out of view and back in, I can see the updated values. I tried `refresh()` method on the list but that makes the list scroll to the top which is undesirable.

So how can I force refresh on just that element?

**Edit: Full code**

```
<lv:RadListView row="1" items="{{ products }}" id="productList">
    <lv:RadListView.listViewLayout>
        <lv:ListViewGridLayout scrollDirection="Vertical" spanCount="2" />
    </lv:RadListView.listViewLayout>

  <lv:RadListView.itemTemplate>
    <GridLayout rows="{{ width+', auto' }}" class="borders">
      <fresco:FrescoDrawee row="0" width="{{ width }}" height="{{ width }}" decodeWidth="{{ width }}" decodeHeight="{{ width }}" imageUri="{{ image }}" placeholderImageUri="~/images/loading.jpg" failureImageUri="~/images/loading.jpg" progressiveRenderingEnabled="true" id="{{ 'product'+id }}" tap="selectItem" />
      <StackLayout row="1" class="card-content bg-white">
        <label text="{{ name }}" class="bold" />
        <Label text="{{ 'Net Weight: '+netWeight+' gms' }}" class="h6 text-black" />
        <GridLayout columns="auto,auto">
            <Label col="0" text="Qty: " class="h6 text-black" />
            <StackLayout col="1" orientation="horizontal" class="qtySelect bg-secondary">
            <Label class="mdi qtyButtons" text="&#xe15c;" pid="{{ id }}" tap="qtyDecrease" />
            <TextField text="{{ quantity }}" keyboardType="Number" verticalAlignment="top" class="qtyText" />
            <Label class="mdi qtyButtons" text="&#xe147;" pid="{{ id }}" tap="qtyIncrease" />
          </StackLayout>
                </GridLayout>
        <Button text="{{ addToCartText }}" class="btn trans-white" padding="0" pid="{{ id }}" tap="addToCart" />
      </StackLayout>
    </GridLayout>
  </lv:RadListView.itemTemplate>
</lv:RadListView>
```

JS

```
const screenWidth = settings.getNumber("screenWidth");
var boxWidth = screenWidth/2;
var page;
var prodSearchCriteria;
var productRadList;
var productsVM;
var products;
var numProductsView;

function loadProducts(criteria){
    http.request({
        url: config.apiUrl+"products.php",
        method: "POST",
        headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
        content: JSON.stringify({
            auth: config.apiAuth,
            criteria: criteria
        })
    }).then(function(request){
        var response = JSON.parse(request.content);

        productsVM.set("numProducts", response.data.length);
        productsVM.set("minWeight", response.min_weight);
        productsVM.set("maxWeight", response.max_weight);
        productsVM.set("designs", response.designs);

        products.length = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < response.data.length; i++) {
            products.push({
                id: response.data[i].id,
                image: config.siteUrl+"/product_img/"+response.data[i].image,
                name: response.data[i].name,
                netWeight: response.data[i].net_weight,
                width: boxWidth,
                min_order: response.data[i].min_order,
                quantity: response.data[i].min_order,
                addToCartText: "Add to Cart"
            });
        }
        productIdsString = productIdsString.slice(0, -1);
        numProductsView.resetNativeView();
    }, function(error){
        console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
    });
}

exports.onLoaded = function(args) {
        page = args.object;
        prodSearchCriteria = page.navigationContext;
        if("filters" in prodSearchCriteria){
        } else {
            prodSearchCriteria.filters = {};
        }

        productsVM = new observableModule.fromObject({
            userAvatar: settings.getString("userAvatar"),
            userEmail: settings.getString("userEmail"),
            cartNumProducts: settings.getNumber("cartNumProducts"),
            cartNetWeight: settings.getNumber("cartNetWeight"),
            cartFineWeight: settings.getNumber("cartFineWeight"),
            cartLabor: settings.getNumber("cartLabor"),
            numProducts: 0,
            minWeight: 0,
            maxWeight: 0,
            designs: []
        });
        products = new observableArrayModule.ObservableArray();

        page.bindingContext = productsVM;
        productsVM.set("products", products);

        numProductsView = view.getViewById(page, "numProducts")
        productRadList = view.getViewById(page, "productList");

        loadProducts(prodSearchCriteria);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to wrap the quantity change in `setTimeout()` of 10 milliseconds

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to bind data again manually (in increase -decrease functions and in textfield’s changed event)?

Comment: Hey what do you mean by rebinding data? And I've shared more code related to loading and binding product information.

Comment: I mean bind complete data again "productsVM.set("products", products);"
btw did you try to change any other component like label? Is problem about only textfield or any component that binding by loadProduct()?